# CSS display lists in horizontal order

Tags: html, css

I need to show several lists `ul` in 3 columns on horizontal order.

The next image is the result when I print the HTML page. In the page fit about 45 school name.

The problem is that I need the blue `ul` fill the first column and then continues on the second column in the first page, then the pink continues until the page ends, then the green column, and so on.

[image]

And this is the Code I create so far.

[

```css
@page{size: A4; margin: 0;}@media print{html, body{width: 210mm; height: 297mm;}}
ul{list-style-type: none; columns: 3; column-fill: balance; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.break{page-break-before: always;}
.element{position: relative; padding-bottom: 0.3cm; }
.column{width: .1cm; height: 100%; display: inline-block; position: absolute;}
.circle{border-radius: 50%; width: .7cm; height: .7cm; font-weight: bold; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: inline-block; text-align: center; line-height: .7cm; margin-right: -8px; z-index: 999; position: relative;}
li:nth-of-type(48n){page-break-after: always; }
table{display: inline; border-left: 5px; padding-left: 10px; border-spacing: 0;}
td{padding: 0;}
li{position:relative}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="type1">
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">1</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #1B67B1;">45</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #1B67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #1B67B1;">School name 45</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="type2">
     <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 101</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">101</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #FF67B1;">109</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #FF67B1;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #FF67B1;">School name 109</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="type3">
     <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">201</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 201</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="circle" style="background-color: #00671f;">221</span>
        <div class="column" style="background-color: #00671f;"></div>
        <table>
          <tr><td style="color: #00671f;">School name 221</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 1</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Address line 2</td></tr>
        </table>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

][2](http:////jsfiddle.net/franknigth/Lo0ftwj3/22/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to page break after each list when printing.

```
@media print {
  ul .type1,
  ul .type2,
  ul .type3 {
    break-after: always;
  }
}
```

Comment: In one page could be about 45 schools, I need a `breack-after` each 45 elements (schools info). Maybe are 50 schools of type1, I need the first 45 school complete the first page, then the other 5 schools need to be the first 5 elements on the second page, and then the second page continues with type2 and type3 in the same order. 
the problem is the order of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `columns` from `ul` styles and add it to the `body` container, this will result in items to follow in rows instead of placing in blocks of `ul`s.

Comment: I try that before, but then the first type of school continues in the second page instead of the second column :(